# Tomato sauce - tomatoes, then juice vs tomatoes & juice

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

Recently I made a simple tomato sauce using canned tomatoes. In the recipe it said to first put the tomatoes in the pan, then the juice. I followed this advice and the sauce was great, but will the sauce turn out great again even if I put tomatoes & juice in the pan at the same time? Does it make a difference putting the juice into the pan after the tomatoes?

If you need more information, this is the [recipe I used](http://www.gilttaste.com/stories/4572-the-most-talked-about-buttery-tomato-pasta-recipe-ever).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like it'd make much difference to that recipe. The juice goes in right after the tomatoes, so it's not like they cook on their own significantly. The one thing you get out of adding the tomatoes first is a way to get them spread evenly around the pan without having to stir, so they're mostly on top of the onions and get gentler heat at first. But you'll be stirring soon anyway, so just dumping it all in wouldn't make much difference at all.